# MySQL stored procedure with variables first steps error #1111

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, upload

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that will accept data sent from PHP to store one or more images inside a MySQL table called "imagenes" .

Table structure *(in Spanish but it's perfectly understandable in English)*:

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|imagenes     |                                          |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|imagenAlbumId|Primary Key INT NN doesn't auto-increment |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|imagenId     |Primary Key INT NN doesn't auto-increment |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|imagenData   |BLOB NN                                   |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|imagenCreada |DATETIME NN                               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
```

each "album" is a collection pertaining to a single item/event and many images are connected through the same albumId which is why I don't want the fields to auto-increment, the ID logic is going to be on the PHP side of things.

The general idea is that images are related to other events/objects, an employee that is cited for some misconduct will have a row added to his record that can contain images of the event, the event is singular but it can have many images.
A product can have multiple images and this is why I chose this design.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to upload multiple images through a single HTML input `<input type="file" name="img" multiple>`
this gets sent to a PHP file that creates an array and then executes a 'CALL' to MySQL with a prepared statement for each file.
image[0] and image[1] etc will CALL the procedure new_album_upload(image_number, image_data), the procedure looks like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS new_album_upload;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE new_album_upload (IN image_number INT, IN image_data BLOB)
BEGIN
IF image_number = 0 THEN SET @album_id = MAX(imagenes.imagenId)+1; 
ELSE SET @album_id = MAX(imagenes.imagenAlbumId); 
END IF;
INSERT INTO imagenes (imagenalbumid, imagenid, imagendata, imagencreada) 
VALUES (@album_id, image_number, image_data, NOW());
END $$ 
DELIMITER;
```

The idea is that PHP will loop over the array, analizing each file and if valid sending it, image[0] will be the first and will trigger the IF to return TRUE and thus set @album_id to be +1 from the highest entry thus far, the next image sent by PHP will be image[1] and thus will set @album_id to be the highest value in the column thus repeating the album id of image[0].

I'm obviously doing something wrong because the procedure stores fine but when I try to CALL it I get an error #1111 "invalid use of group function" and from what I've read on similar questions it has something to do with using MAX() but all questions I've seen talk about the use with WHERE, which I don't use in this case.
Maybe also pertinent: I'm using PHPmyAdmin for this and executing the procedure through the built-in modal menu, it queries the following when executing:

```
SET @p0='0';
SET @p1='IMAGE 1-1';
CALL `new_album_upload`(@p0, @p1);
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible (or even logical) in this case? am I using the wrong approach or is this some syntax thing I'm botching? 
I have zero experience with databases and am learning as I go so it's very possible that I've got this backwards somehow and I'm open to suggestions to different approaches.
The reason I'm trying to used a stored procedure was to also not make a call to MySQL to see what ID was next and then sending that back with the new request, I want to be able to just send the request and the data and have MySQL take care of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `album_id` is an AUTO INCREMENT column, so why are you generating a new number for it manually. Very dangerous in a multi user environment. Let autoincrement do it job

Comment: I'm avoiding auto increment because if I upload 2 images the first is going to have the correct album_id and trigger AUTO INCREMENT so the second image of the same upload will have a different album_id which is not what I want.

Comment: Album ID should be a foreign key that references the album table. You should auto-increment it there, and then use that ID when adding to the imagenes table.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any benefit to using an extra table that only stores this relation as opposed to having a single table with 2 keys? It seems to me that having a single simple structure would be better since the albums themselves hold no value here, I'm only interested in the images and grouping them, an "albums" table would hold no data except just an id.

Comment: What's the point of grouping them into albums if there's no album-specific information? Maybe you should have album names, for instance?

Comment: @Barmar the images are used for specific events that are stored in many tables. some albums are just a couple images of a specific product, some are groups of images regarding an employee citation. Those tables already hold all the information I need about the group of images. so having a foreign key in the Products table pointing to the albumid and have it refrence all the images from a single table is useful to me. I'm probably not being clear here, this isn't supposed to be a sort of galary. Products, CustomerAddress,Supplier tables will have a foreign key pointing to imagenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error #1111 "invalid use of group function"

Yeah obviously since there is no `FROM` clause and you just can't get the `MAX()` like that as in below code segment

```
THEN SET @album_id = MAX(imagenes.imagenId)+1
```

You should change this to

```
select @album_id = MAX(imagenId) + 1
from imagenes
```

(OR)

```
@album_id = (SELECT MAX(imagenId) + 1 from imagenes)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick, I've changed it to `(SELECT MAX(imagenId) FROM imagenes)+1; ELSE SET @album_id =(SELECT MAX(imagenAlbumId) FROM imagenes); END IF;` I'm now not getting the expected behavior when image_number = 0. but I'm one step closer. I just assumed I can call the MAX function wherever.